# Setting a Variable as a Class in PHP

Tags: php, class, variables

Want to know if I can dynamically create a PHP class by stating it as a variable.

i.e.

```
class $vaiable {

  public $foo2,
         $foo3,
         $foo4;


  function __construct(array $data = null) {
    if( empty($data) ) 
      return;

    foreach( $data as $field => $value ) {
      $this->$field = $value;
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Why not try it? I got: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting T_STRING`

Comment: I did, it didn't work. Was wondering if there's another way to dynamically set a class.

Comment: There are __get and __set [magic methods](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php) that allow you to control getting and setting in a class .

Comment: Why you want to do it?

Comment: @hek2mgl An ORM, most likely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the one and only thing that I've ever used and allowed others to use [`eval()`](http://php.net/eval) for, provided that the variable content is strictly controlled, i.e., no arbitrary user input, preferably checked against a whitelist, and so on.

E.g.:

```
<?php
    eval('class '.$variable.' {
        public $foo;
        private $bar;

        // ...etc
    }');
?>
```

Comment: Although one should not write an application that relies on `eval()`, it's the only working answer to that. +1

Comment: Thanks @pilsetnieks it worked. Although I don't think it's the most effective method it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Are you looking to create a new instance of a class, where the class name is not immediately known? If so, this is valid in PHP:

```
class SomeClass
{
    public function printSomething()
    {
        echo "You did it!";
    }
}

$className = "SomeClass";

$instance = new $className();

$instance->printSomething();
```